# How to turn on components by event?

Tags: angular

I have a lot of CRUD event operations for many entities like create user, create task, create permission.

I want to show forms of them(components) on the left sidebar. So user can work at the same time with only one sidebar content.

Other words instead dialogs I want to show content in the sidebar.

I decided to send event messages with type of event and data using `Suject()`.

In sidebar component I have switch inside template like this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="sidebarType">
                  <ng-template ngSwitchCase="CREATE_USER">Component here</ng-template>
                  <ng-template ngSwitchCase="CREATE_PERMISSION">Component here</ng-template>
                  ...etc
                </div>
```

Problem is I have a lot of `switchCase` what I dislike.

How to improve this approach?

Comment: what is it that u don't like about switchCase??

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with a router children?
Or ngIf statements instead of switchCases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular feature is **Dynamic Component Loader.** Please refer [this](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) link for how to use this feature.